# Matrix multiplication: maintain scipy.sparse.dok_matrix format

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, sparse-matrix, linear-algebra

I am trying to use scipy to perform sparse linear algebra calculations in the dok (dictionary of keys) format. 
When I multiply two matricies together the format changes from dok type to csr format which is an inefficient format for the data and subsequent operations.

How can I keep the dok format?

I have looked at the docs:

- [scipy sparse matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html)
- [dok_matrix](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.dok_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.dok_matrix)

But cannot see any information automatic type conversion or if and how it can be avoided.

See this example:

```py
from scipy.sparse import dok_matrix

my_mat = dok_matrix([[1,2], [3,4]])

print(type(my_mat.dot(my_mat)))
print(type(my_mat @ my_mat))
```

shows that the format has been changed:

```
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just convert back:

```
result = result.todok()
```

CSR may be an inefficient format for subsequent operations (or maybe not, we can't tell), but it's great for matrix multiplication. Trying to make the matrix multiplication code operate on a DOK result natively would be slower than just converting the result.

Comment: It's not great for multiplying the matricies that I would like to multiply. I am not interested in a format which has anything other than a logarithmic overhead in the dimensions of the matrix.
E.g. 
```python
    my_mat = dok_matrix((100000000,100000000))  
    my_mat[50000000, 50000000] = 1.0  
   print(type((my_mat @ my_mat)))  
```
takes more than 3s to evaluate on my computer.

Comment: @Patrick: Then adjust your code to eliminate all-zero rows and columns, if your data is *that* sparse. You can put them back later.

Comment: Please let me know if it is not possible to perform linear algebra in scipy without a polynomial overhead in the size of the dimensions of the vectors/matricies. 
I do not know a-priori where the zeros will be and they will change throughout operations.

Comment: @Patrick: You may not know a priori, but you can check. In any case, if SciPy did have anything specialized for matrix multiplication on matrices that sparse, it would probably work by taking out the all-zeros rows and columns, doing the multiplication, and converting back, just like I'm suggesting now.

Comment: this would be satisfactory if I could remove the zeros without writing a loop in python that scales with the number of non-zero elements. Is this possible?
The reason I'd like to use scipy in the first place is to avoid python overhead.

Comment: @Patrick: But you're *already incurring* Python overhead by using DOK. `scipy.sparse.dok_matrix` is backed by a regular Python dict full of regular Python tuples and ints. Anything SciPy does with it will involve regular Python loops. There's no fancy C stuff going on under the hood.

Comment: Ah. Thanks for letting me know!

Comment: `csr` format does use compiled code for its sparse matrix multiplication and element wise.  It tends to be faster than the dense `dot` when sparsity is on the order of 1%.  Nearly all sparse math is done by first converting the matrices to `csr`.  Conversion back is optional.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by @user2357112 `csr` is good for linear algebra. The cost of conversion is, however, significant. As `dok` is not the only format that supports acceptable time editing it is worthwhile to check out the other option which is `lil`. Depending on your use case you may save quite a bit of time:

```
from scipy import sparse
from timeit import timeit

a = random(100,100,0.1,format='lil')
b = random(100,100,0.1,format='dok')
a
# <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#         with 1000 stored elements in LInked List format>
b
# <100x100 sparse matrix of type '<class 'numpy.float64'>'
#         with 1000 stored elements in Dictionary Of Keys format>
timeit(lambda:(a@a).tolil(),number=100)*10
# 1.491789099527523
timeit(lambda:(b@b).todok(),number=100)*10
# 4.220661079743877
```

Note that `a@a`/`b@b` is rather dense in this example, if we choose a sparser case the difference is less pronounced:

```
a = random(100,100,0.01,format='lil')
b = random(100,100,0.01,format='dok')

timeit(lambda:(a@a).tolil(),number=100)*10
# 0.6880075298249722
timeit(lambda:(b@b).todok(),number=100)*10
# 0.7450748200062662
```